# Expression tree depth limitations

Tags: c#, delegates, expression, expression-trees, anonymous-function

I'm facing a problem trying to call Compile() on the LambdaExpression of type Expression<Func<MyType, bool>> which has a depth around 400. And lesser values do not cause any problems. And I can't find anything about such kind of limitation. Can anyone clarify this? Can I increase this limit?

upd:
Sorry, forgot to mention, I'm getting StackOverflowException:

*An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Core.dll
{Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.}*

Comment: what is "a problem"? what happens? a `StackOverflowException`? or ...?

Comment: For me this slightly falls into the Raymond Chen category [If you have to ask, you're probably doing something wrong](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/03/01/1775759.aspx)

Comment: @AakashM thanks for another keeper bookmark :)  Agreed 100%

Comment: Yes, I totally agree too :) And I'm sure there is way to optimize expression tree in my case and decrease the depth and I'm trying to make this right now. Nevertheless it was interesting to know the true reason behind this behavior. So, Chris, thanks for that;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are legitimately running into a limit on the stack size (although I question the wisdom of a 400+ item lambda).  The easiest way to bypass that is to create a new thread specifically for performing this compilation with a larger stack, using the thread constructor that takes the stack size as an argument: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149581.aspx

Call compile in that thread and increase the stack size argument as necessary.  It is in bytes I believe, which would make the default about 1048576, so start there and raise it as needed.

Comment: This solution is now limited to Full Trust.  "Beginning with the .NET Framework 4, only fully trusted code can set maxStackSize to a value that is greater than the default stack size (1 megabyte). If a larger value is specified for maxStackSize when code is running with partial trust, maxStackSize is ignored and the default stack size is used. No exception is thrown. Code at any trust level can set maxStackSize to a value that is less than the default stack size."